# Use composer based library without composer wrapped in class of same name?

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I'm trying to use the PHPMoney library, wrapped in my own class called Money. The main application does not use namespaces and I have no desire to. I've placed the src files for PHPMoney in a folder, and am trying to include them in a way that their `money` class doesn't interfere with my `money` class, and without modifying any of their code. I'm not using composer.

I'm trying this:

```
require __APP_PATH_VAR.'MoneyPHP/Money.php';
require __APP_PATH_VAR.'MoneyPHP/Currency.php';

use Money\Currency;
use Money\Money;

// Create my own wrapper class called Money
class Money {    

   protected $oPHPMoney;

   public function __construct($Amount,$Currency='USD'){    
      $this->oPHPMoney =new Money\Money($Amount, new Currency($Currency));
   }

}
```

Which tells me I `Cannot declare class Money because the name is already in use`.

How do I include their library without it interfering with my global namespace classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `Money\Money` with an aliased name.

E.g.:

```
use Money\Money as Money2;
```

And then:

```
public function __construct($amount, $currency='USD'){    
  $this->oPHPMoney =new Money2($amount, new Currency($currency));
}
```